# User defined derived type IO file compile on gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am trying to compile the sample code provided in example 1 of [this link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/678729) using GNU Fortran. I have placed the source code in a .f95 file called "Test" and tried to compile it in `cmd` using

`gfortran test.95`

This throws quite a few errors as shown below:

```
      GENERIC :: READ (FORMATTED) => UDIO_READ_ARRAY
                    1
Error: Expected '=>' at (1)
test.f95:12:17:

   INTERFACE WRITE(FORMATTED)
                 1
Error: Syntax error: Trailing garbage in INTERFACE statement at (1)
test.f95:13:21:

      MODULE PROCEDURE UDIO_WRITE_ARRAY
                     1
Error: MODULE PROCEDURE at (1) must be in a generic module interface
test.f95:14:5:

   END INTERFACE
     1
Error: Expecting END MODULE statement at (1)
test.f95:51:6:

   USE TYPES
      1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'types.mod' for reading at (1): No such file
 or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: Please write out the errors in the question. What happens if you try a simple hello world code?

Comment: I must second that, it is *very important* to copy and paste everything as text. Especially the output from your screenshot. It needs to be searchable so that others with the same problem can find a solution. If you don't know how to copy from Windows terminal, just search the internet https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/copy-to-the-clipboard-from-the-windows-command-prompt/ Even the code can become unaccessible some day, but it is likely copyrighted.

Comment: A simple hello world code ... well... works. Otherwise I would be posting that as my initial question. I have just copied the `cmd` line code and pasted it. There was no way I was gonna write it out lol. Thanks for the tip @VladimirF

Comment: you should specify the gfortran version. There may simply be some newish constructs in there that are not supported by your compiler.   Aside did you really feel the need to include your `D;` fat finger mistake in the post?

Comment: Like what @agentp commented -- from their release notes it looks like `fortran` only implements derived type i/o in v7 and later.

Comment: I downvoted you because 1. the original code has not been provided. read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please. 2. Sorry to say this but the code block is embarrassingly sloppy. you have even included the mistaken `D;` and the error message associated to that. you should have cleaned that up first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is this happening?

Because gfortran 5.1.0 dosn't support derived type input/output (DTIO).

How can I fix it?

Download MinGW-w64 version>=7.1.0 
https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files .